# Google Play Upload failed [package name error] despite correct package name

Tags: android, apk, phonegap-build

I'm updating an App on Google Play I last updated successfully about a year ago. This time when I submit it, I get this:-

**Upload failed
Your APK needs to have the package name uktaxrates2012.xxyyzz.com.**

However in the config.xml for Phonegap Build it specifically says:-

**id = "uktaxrates2012.xxyyzz.com"**   and if I take a look at the same info within the phonegap build website settings tab, it clearly believes the same thing.

As far as I can see (and I've cut and pasted the package name a few times to make sure there's no hidden typos) the package name is as required, but Play's
having none of it. If I go back and rebuild an earlier version of the app, the one that's currently live, I still have the same problem. Only an apk actually built a year ago is accepted.

The signing certificate is the same as it was a year ago; it's been in use since 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a new project and after you finish with package name that you just copy everything from the old project(I know it's not easy)

In Package Name go to Edit and type whatever you like following the 
sample com.domain.appname

I hope this helps :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but - I'm not using Andriod Studio, I'm using Phonegap Build.

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry I wasn't aware that phonegap build is a program,I thought it's the name of your app

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the package name of the update is different to the package name that is already uploaded.

The names have to be identical. I just had this same error (I had a spelling mistake in the package name - com.awesoemapp.cool instead of com.awesomeapp.cool

I know you think its the same but check again.

You should use the naming convention I have show here too, the com. at the beginning. Just because.

Comment: Hi. I've checked and they are identical. On the phonegap forums I've narrowed it down to this: because the package name doesn't have.com at the beginning, *now* phonegap build can't work with it even though it used to. I inherited the job and package name from another agency. So the question becomes - why can phonegap build not cope with this package name when it used to be able to.

Comment: I don't know. Is this a released app? If not just redo it all